# IPv6 EUI-64, how to activate privacy extension on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: netplan, ipv6

In my home network I have dual IPv4 + IPv6 stack. IPv4 runs DHCP whereas IPv6 depends on SLAAC.

On my Ubuntu Server 20.04 the `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file looks like this:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.4.43/24
            dhcp6: false
            accept-ra: true
            gateway4: 10.0.4.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 10.0.6.3
                search:
                - example.com
    version: 2
```

It works fine however the IPv6 address that Ubuntu generates is standard EUI64, which allows you to read network adapter's MAC address. For comparison, Windows operating system generates a new randomised IPv6 address (or at least last 64 bits) every 24 hours that does not depends on network adapter's MAC address.

My question: Is it possible for Ubuntu to generate temporary IPv6 address like Windows does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented on https://netplan.io/reference, you can specify `ipv6-privacy: true` to enable IPV6 privacy extensions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.